# Why can't I access the first token returned from Java's StringTokenizer?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I'm using Buffered Reader to pass individual lines of a file to Java's `StringTokenizer`. The file is structurd as follows:

```
"2,0";"foo";"foo.doc";"12345"
"2,4";"foo";"foo.doc";"34567";"foo7";"foo7.doc";"45678";"foo6";"foo6.doc";"56789";"foo5";"foo5.doc";"67890";"foo4";"foo4.doc";"23456"   
"3,0";"foo7";"foo7.doc";"34567"
"3,0";"foo6";"foo6.doc";"45678"
"3,0";"foo5";"foo5.doc";"56789"
"3,0";"foo4";"foo4.doc";"67890"
```

Here's the code I'm using.

```
public class parse {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("whidata0.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)); 
    while((scrubbedInput=br.readLine())!=null) {
      StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(scrubbedInput, ";", false);
      int tokens = strTok.countTokens();
      while (strTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
        tok01 = strTok.nextToken();
      }
      System.out.println("  scrubbed: " + scrubbedInput);
      System.out.println("    tokens: " + tokens);
      System.out.println("     tok01: " + tok01);
    }
  }
}
```

which yields this result.

```
scrubbed: "2,0";"foo";"foo.doc";"12345" 
  tokens: 4
   tok01: 12345  scrubbed: "2,4";"foo";"foo.doc";"34567";"foo7";"foo7.doc";"45678";"foo6";"foo6.doc";"56789";"foo5";"foo5.doc";"67890";"foo4";"foo4.doc";"23456"    
  tokens: 16
   tok01: 23456
scrubbed: "3,0";"foo7";"foo7.doc";"34567"
  tokens: 4
   tok01: 34567
scrubbed: "3,0";"foo6";"foo6.doc";"45678"
  tokens: 4
   tok01: 45678
scrubbed: "3,0";"foo5";"foo5.doc";"56789"
  tokens: 4
   tok01: 56789
scrubbed: "3,0";"foo4";"foo4.doc";"67890"               
  tokens: 4
   tok01: 67890
```

When using `nextToken()` what is the starting token supposed to be? It appears as though `StringTokenizer` starts with token `0`, so that the `nextToken()` is actually token `1` -- the second physical token. I did not see a `firstToken()` method in Java documentation, nor did I see a way to assign specific tokens to specific variables (e.g., `String myToken = strTok.tokenNumber(0)` etc.). What do I need to do to access the first physical token in my String?

Comment: The code here appears not complete nor is it the code that produced this output. e.g. the first `"tok01: 12345"` should be `tok01: "foo.doc"` for the code shown here.

Comment: Oops...cut and pasted an older version of the test file...that's been updated above to reflect the correct file I was using.

Comment: That seems more appropriate. Your `while (strTok.hasMoreTokens()) tok01 = strTok.nextToken();` loop assigns the last token of each line to `tok01` - which may or may not be what you intend to do. `strTok.nextToken()` however will give you the first token the first time you call it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code does not reflect the output, but anyhow you might want to use the `String.split()` functions instead of a tokenizer, when you want to access an arbitrary token, e.g.:

```
    String st = "a;b;c";        
    String[] tokens = st.split(";");
    System.out.println(tokens[0]);
```

will print out "a", the first token.

The `StringTokenizer` class allows only to access token after token, you cannot access a token in a random access way. But you can use it also to access the first token:

```
    String st = "a;b;c";        
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(st,";");
    System.out.println(tokenizer.nextToken());
```

Will also print out "a", the first token.

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite the value of `tokens` in your loop.

Try this and have a look at the output.

```
public class parse {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("whidata0.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)); 
    while((scrubbedInput=br.readLine())!=null) {
      StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(scrubbedInput, ";", false);
      int tokens = strTok.countTokens();
      while (strTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
        tok01 = strTok.nextToken();
        System.out.println("     tok01: " + tok01);
      }
      System.out.println("  scrubbed: " + scrubbedInput);
      System.out.println("    tokens: " + tokens);
      System.out.println("last tok01: " + tok01);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The point is moot now since OP had not shown correct input. If you make assumptions, state them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you printing the `System.out.println("     tok01: " + tok01);` out of while loop

```
  StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(scrubbedInput, ";", false);
  int tokens = strTok.countTokens();
  while (strTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
    tok01 = strTok.nextToken();// here is the problem
  }
  System.out.println("  scrubbed: " + scrubbedInput);
  System.out.println("    tokens: " + tokens);
  System.out.println("     tok01: " + tok01);
```

I think it should be like below

```
   StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(scrubbedInput, ";", false);
   int tokens = strTok.countTokens();
   System.out.println("  scrubbed: " + scrubbedInput);
   System.out.println("    tokens: " + tokens);
   while (strTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
       tok01 = strTok.nextToken();           
       System.out.println("     tok01: " + tok01);
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your while loop iterates over all tokens first i think it is a misplaced `}`.

```
    while (strTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
      tok01 = strTok.nextToken();                  
      System.out.println("     tok01: " + tok01);
    }
```